# Wrong position in Custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, adapter

I have created a ***Custom Adapter*** to manage some **Buttons** inside each **ListView** item. If I scroll-down the list, and I click a button, the adapter take a wrong position.

### LISTVIEW

### item 1

### item 2

### item 3

### item 4

### item 5

### item 6

### item 7

### POSITION AFTER CLICK

### 0

### 1

### 2

### 3

### 4

### 5

### 0

This is my adapter:

```
public DoubleListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DoubleListItems> items,
        String Tag) {
    super(context, 0, items);
    this.Tag = Tag;
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    final int Position = position;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.double_list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        final DoubleListItems i = (DoubleListItems) items.get(position);
        holder.item = i;
        holder.Icon = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.IconaDoubleList);
        holder.Title = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.TitoloDoubleList);
        holder.SecondLineDesc = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.SecondaLineaDesc);
        holder.SecondLineValue = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.SecondaLineaValue);
        holder.ThirdLineDesc = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.TerzaLineaDesc);
        holder.ThirdLineValue = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.TerzaLineaValue);
        holder.Delete = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ButtonDeleteItem);
        holder.Set = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ButtonSetiItem);
        holder.Delete.setTag(holder);
        holder.Delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        holder.Set.setTag(holder);
        holder.Set.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Log.e("DOUBLELIST ADAPTER ", "Position: " + Position);
                String Code = i.getKey();
                // String Code = holder.item.getKey();
                Intent intent;

                    Costanti.curLocale = Costanti.LocaliLavorati.Item("L"
                            + Code);
                    intent = new Intent(context, IncassiTab.class);
                    if (Costanti.curLocale != null) {
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Locale nullo",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                }


        });

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    final DoubleListItems i = holder.item;
    if (i != null) {
        holder.Set.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.Delete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.Icon.setImageResource(i.getIcon());
        holder.Title.setText(i.getTitle());
        holder.SecondLineDesc.setText(i.getSecondLineDesc());
        if (i.getType().equals("N")) {
            holder.SecondLineDesc.setTextColor(context.getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.grigio));
        }

        if (!i.getSecondLineValue().equals("")) {
            holder.SecondLineValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.SecondLineDesc.setTextColor(context.getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.orange));
            holder.Icon.setImageResource(i.getIcon());
            holder.Title.setText(i.getTitle());
            holder.SecondLineDesc.setText(i.getSecondLineDesc());
            holder.SecondLineValue.setText(i.getSecondLineValue());

            if (!i.getThirdLineDesc().equals("")) {
                holder.Set.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.Delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.ThirdLineDesc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.ThirdLineValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.ThirdLineDesc.setText(i.getThirdLineDesc());
                holder.ThirdLineValue.setText(i.getThirdLineValue());

                holder.Delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.Set.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.ThirdLineDesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.ThirdLineDesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        } else {
            holder.SecondLineValue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.ThirdLineDesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.ThirdLineValue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.Set.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.Delete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    public ViewHolder() {

    }

    protected DoubleListItems item;
    protected Button Delete;
    protected Button Set;
    protected ImageView Icon;
    protected TextView Title;
    protected TextView SecondLineDesc;
    protected TextView SecondLineValue;
    protected TextView ThirdLineDesc;
    protected TextView ThirdLineValue;

}
```

This is the solution:

```
if (convertView == null) {
 Your code
}else{
 Your code
} 

holder.Set.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Your code
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ListView taking wrong position? What do you want it to do when you scroll down?

Comment: its is because of your implementation of `getView` and how listview recycles views.

Comment: @KickAss When i click on the button inside the 7th listview items, The position is wrong, and the the software load wrong data.

Comment: @Raghunandan Is there a solution?

Comment: @user2516977 I think you have over complicated the implementation of the Custom Adapter, as @Raghunandan says, `getView` needs to be correctly implemented, unfortunately, I cannot help in this case, best of luck.

Comment: @user2516977 there is. look at the examples of custom adapter by searching on stackoverflow. You find many examples

Comment: you need to add int position field in your holder class

Comment: Hi guys. I've solved. i've put "onClickListner" after if/else. Now I edit my answer to show you the solution. Thank you.

Comment: @user2516977: you can post your solution as answer and accept it.

Comment: `if (convertView == null) {
 Your code
}else{
 Your code
} 

holder.Set.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Your code
        }
}   `